# iCloud reports more space than expected

Tags: icloud, finder, storage

iCloud says that iCloud Drive takes up 592MB of space:

[image: iCloud 592MB Report]

However, when I open the iCloud Drive folder on Finder and sum the sizes of the stuff shown there, I get a much smaller sum:

[image: iCloud Drive Size Sum]

What is the reason for this? How can I free up more space in my iCloud Drive?

Comment: Have you checked for hidden files or folders?

Answer (score 1):

Solar Mike's guess was correct. I had deleted stuff that was in my iCloud Drive and those "deleted" stuff was still taking up space.

When you delete something on your Mac, it goes to `~/.Trash`. However, when you delete something that was on iCloud Drive, that doesn't go to `~/.Trash`. It goes to:

```
/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/.Trash
```

So make sure that you check out the iCloud Drive's trash if there is a big mismatch between the size reported by Finder and by iCloud.